# Joomla Component - Related Table

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

I have built a component which has two tables of data, these are related by an ID.

I have it working so that when you are viewing table A, you can click a field and proceed to the view of table B - which is filtered by the the ID from table A.

My last challenge: When the user clicks the AddNew button when viewing table B we need to take the related ID into the addnew form so it saves in a hidden field.

Any pointers welcomed please!
Up against a deadline, pulling too much hair out, and overdosing on caffeine!!

Comment: Pass the ID as a GET variable `?id=x`, and insert it into the hidden if present, with `echo (int)JRequest::getVar('id')`.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

a. add a hidden field in the view of table A rows with the related id

```
<form method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm" > 
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="yourid" value="...." />
</form>
```

b. override the `add()` function in your controller of a field of table B (the one that extends the `JControllerForm`), add in the redirect url the `yourid` parameter

```
class ...Controller... extends JControllerForm {

    public function add() {
        //...
        $yid = $app->input->get('yourid');
        $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=' . 
            $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_item .
            '&yourid=' . $yid . $this->getRedirectToItemAppend(), false));
        //...
    }
}
```

c. in the model of the table b you can get the `yourid` input parameter, and edit the rest queries.

```
  public function __construct($config = array()) {
        // .. 
        $this->yid = $app->input->get('yourid');
        parent::__construct($config);
  }
```

Hope this helps.